# How to plot data from DataGridView into Radar chart?

Tags: c#, datagridview, charts

I'm having a column in my DataGridView which contains a number of data.

Total DataGridView column length is 140 rows. And the data which i need to plot in Radar chart is in column 19. Here column 19 is having about 12 rows of data and remaining 132 rows are empty only.

For your reference:
[image]

My main task is to create Windrose chart.

I tried this to plot those data in radar chart,

```
         {
         chart1.Visible = true;
         chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
         //this.chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[19].DataPropertyName;
         this.chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[19].DataPropertyName;
         chart1.DataBind();
         }
```

but chart is not generating. Can anyone help regarding my radar chart plotting ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Why have you commented out XValueMember line? How are you populating your data grid?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not getting any errors, but chart is not generating. Here i'm populating my datagridview from excel sheet.

Comment: please post the code that populates your data grid...